# Segue Issue when switching views

Tags: ios, segue

I am currently getting an error on my app when I am performing a segue to another view which is performed by clicking on an Image View.

The error says: fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an optional value. I am not sure why this is happening but below is an image where the [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M3542.png) is occuring. I am assuming there is something wrong with the segue because the error occurs when clicking the button. However the error is highlighted on this piece of code which is confusing me?

This is the code:

```
func loadComments() {

    let postCommentRef = FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("post-comments").child(self.postId)

    postCommentRef.observe(.childAdded, with: {
        snapshot in
        print("observe key")
        print(snapshot.key)
        FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("comments").child(snapshot.key).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: {
            snapshotComment in

            if let dict = snapshot.value as? [String: Any] {

                //Retrieving from the database - post Model created class

                let newComment = Comment.transformComment(dict: dict)

                self.getUser(uid: newComment.uid!, completed: {

                    self.comments.append(newComment)
                    self.tableView.reloadData()


                })

            }
        })
    })

}
```

Comment: The only line that could cause a problem is self.tableView.reloadData(). Maybe it's trying to reload tableview that IBOutlet is not connected from storyboard or it's not loaded yet

Comment: The line that is causing an issue is: let postCommentRef = FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("post-comments").child(self.postId)

Comment: Can you check if the ImageView is connect to any IBOutlets/Segues. A common problem happens when you might have connect ImageView to an outlet that you might have later deleted or renamed.

Comment: I just double checked, everything is 100% connected properly with the correct names

Comment: So self.postId must be nil ;)